# Trying to create a jQuery plugin to dynamically fill images inside Foundation modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am new in Foundation and I am trying to create a jQuery plugin to dynamically fill a modal with images, and then modal will be opened after click on some button. But modal does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.js"></script>

    <style>
        img {
            max-width: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="Slider" class="button">Open Modal</a>

    <script id="slideShow" type="text/template">
        <div class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>

            <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
        </div>
    </script>


    <script>
        (function($) {
            /*
             *  expecting:
             *   - array of attributes for img tag
             *   - text/template tag
             */
            $.fn.imageSlider = function(array, element, location) {
                // check if element is instance of jQuery object, if not then make it
                if (element instanceof jQuery == false) {
                    element = $(element);
                }

                // base template of image
                var template = "<img />";

                // loop through all images and add them to element
                for (var obj of array) {
                    element.find(".modal-body").append($(template).attr(obj));
                }

                // random ID generator
                var rand = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

                // show modal on click over image
                element.attr("id", rand);
                this.attr("data-reveal-id", rand);

                // append element to this
                location.append(element);
            }
        })(jQuery);


        var array = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            array.push({
                src: "https://placehold.it/350x350"
            });
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#Slider").imageSlider(array, $("#slideShow").html(), $("body"));
            $(document).foundation();
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AJAX - we wrote a couple of lessons on doing this 2 different ways:
http://zurb.com/university/lessons/ajaxing-dynamic-content-with-foundation
and 
http://zurb.com/university/lessons/dynamically-update-your-web-pages